# How to define a type for the nested function's parameter?

Tags: typescript

I wrote the below code for building methods chain:

```
type Chain<T, U> = { value: T } & Record<
  keyof U,
  (...args: any) => Chain<T, U>
>;

const createChain =
  <T, U>(funcs: U & { [key: string]: (value: T) => (...args: any) => T }) =>
  (value: T) => {
    const chainMethods = Object.keys(funcs).reduce((acc, funcName) => {
      acc[funcName as keyof U] = (...funcsArgs) =>
        createChain<T, U>(funcs)(funcs[funcName](value)(...funcsArgs));
      return acc;
    }, {} as Record<keyof U, (...args: any) => Chain<T, U>>);
    return { value, ...chainMethods };
  };

const add = (value: number) => (num: number, isGood: boolean) => value + num;
const minus = (value: number) => (num: number) => value - num;

const data = 100;
const chain = createChain({ add, minus });
const dataWithChain = chain(data);

dataWithChain.add(12, false); // correct, but the type is any
dataWithChain.minus(12); // correct, but the type is any
dataWithChain.add(12); // incorrect and no warning
dataWithChain.minus(12, "test"); // incorrect and no warning
```

It works but the IDE cannot check the type of chain methods' parameter (I believe it's because I set `(...args: any)`) in `Chain<T, U>`. How to build a dynamic type check if the types of object's values are not same?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKbzgm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes. I think approach is correct. May I have more explanation about your approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `U` type parameter contains the information you need, but `Record<keyof U,  (...args: any) => Chain<T, U>>` doesn't try to do anything with `args`, as you said.  What you can do is write a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `U` and for each method, you can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract the relevant parameter list type.  Like this:

```
type Chain<T, U> = { value: T } & { [K in keyof U]: (...args:
    U[K] extends (x: T) => (...args: infer A) => T ? A : never
) => Chain<T, U> }
```

You expect each method of `U` to be of the form `(x: T) => (...args: ???) => T`.  The point is that you can use a conditional type with `infer A` to extract the `???` type.

Once you do that everything more or less works as designed, except that your implementation needs some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and other type loosening with [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to prevent compiler errors.  There's no way the type checker will be able to verify that the output of `reduce()` will be of the correct form, so we won't even try:

```
const createChain =
    <T, U>(funcs: U & { [key: string]: (value: T) => (...args: any) => T }) =>
        (value: T) => {
            const chainMethods = Object.keys(funcs).reduce((acc, funcName) => {
                acc[funcName as keyof U] = (...funcsArgs: any) =>
                    createChain<T, U>(funcs)(funcs[funcName](value)(...funcsArgs));
                return acc;
            }, {} as any);
            return { value, ...chainMethods } as Chain<T, U> // just assert here;
        };
```

Now you can see the desired behavior:

```
const add = (value: number) => (num: number, isGood: boolean) => value + num;
const minus = (value: number) => (num: number) => value - num;
const data = 100;
const chain = createChain({ add, minus });
const dataWithChain = chain(data);

dataWithChain.add(12, false); // okay
dataWithChain.minus(12); // okay
dataWithChain.add(12); // error, expected 2 args
dataWithChain.minus(12, "test"); // error, expected 1 arg
dataWithChain.minus("oops"); // error, string is not number
dataWithChain.add(12, false).minus(12, "oops"); // error on minus, expected 1 arg
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VA3rQikTNJoAsU4AEIBbMaw9XkCqGEDYbBT7bFaMiXgEpvIUNmszmAjgkJoAOLie5MF7V6jlFBTe1QADUUELyL1J1DyNQIYzkomndzqnzneLo+bQ6gAFoO9nu8nijYKghHgBGAAMW6XpxKnMebIqEG98nIqZsOD7hY9SqT+9XwAQAHUkLdvUfOfInwh73p9F-N8P05WY03kDcACY4RoCMlX9QNxGEBAQEAtdgLgb1FBvEMIMg+CAygJCULQ58MKwy88IIwMAlUcRVBwCxIC+CB00golvFI1930w0CcL+KCcAAIisIohOosxVDohizHMZirHTDcOPULjyL4-s-iE6swE0cTFQQyTpJwAYhkEewUHEYoR0SPQgJ4ijwMEqBJFgtFsI0vDhO03SJNo+iiO1fjGLkz4FKgJS5hyAC9CAA)